# How to fix regex Python to detect mmyy?

Tags: python, regex

I have write own regex to detect is it `mmyy` or `mm-yy` format:

```
^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))[\/\.\-]*((2[0-9])|([0-9]))$
```

[Demo is](https://regex101.com/r/IsKzHM/1)

Problem is this regex validates this wrong format: `036`.

How to fit it?

Comment: `036` matches because `((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))` matches `03` and `((2[0-9])|([0-9]))` matches `6` (the second group matches single numbers). I'm actually not sure what `yy` should be. Is it a year? Which range of years? Can it be any number from 00 to 99? You probably want to modify the second group. Note: the backslashes in `[\/\.\-]` aren't necessary: `[/.-]` should work as well and I'd suggest to use `{0,1}` instead of `*` to avoid matching something like `03----45`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `mm-yy` and `mmyy` can be matched by the following regular expression (assuming `yy` can be from `00` to `99`):

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[/.-]?([0-9]{2})$
```

Comment: How to set limit for yy from 20 to 40?

Comment: Like this? `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/.-]?((2[0-9]))$`? From `2*`?

Comment: @Mamed `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/.-]?([23][0-9]|40)$`